# Passed string from the another ViewController is not working with NSUrl

Tags: ios, string, ios7, nsurlconnection

I am  getting the  PassedUserId value from another view.I can print the value in log. but its not assigning to the url string. Here i am trying to pass the text along with image.

```
NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",PassedUserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,gender,imagename,ageTextfield.text];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);
```

Comment: Does the string contain spaces or non-standard characters (e.g. Swedish, Japanese, etc)? If so the URL will become nil unless you escape it using e.g. NSString's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

Comment: Please encode the url . . may be there are special characters. .

Comment: what is the type of PassedUserId

Comment: string @IQworldMaster

Comment: ok then please use this for string and problem will be solved  :  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: where should i do this change

Comment: in 4th line   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that you have swapped the two values:

`stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@...",CategoryId,PassedUserId`

Could you be more specific about what datatypes the `CategoryId` and `PassedUserId` have?

If they're strings, you're doing it right. If they are datatype integer though, you should use `%i` instead of `%@`.